# How do I revert a git-svn branch to SVN HEAD?

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a local git repository which tracks a remote SVN repository via `git svn`. I have made and committed some changes in the local git repository, but now I'd like to create a branch that reflects SVN HEAD in order to make some changes to the code as it stands in SVN, because  I don't want to propagate the changes in my git master to SVN just yet. How can I go about this?

Immediate follow-up: I will need to make and commit changes to SVN HEAD, then merge them back into my git master. How do I go about this? Do I `git merge` the 'svn-edits' branch into master, or do I do a `git svn rebase`?

Comment: Seriously? You can do that with git and svn!?  Wild!!

Comment: Yeah, there is a small program called git-svn (see man git-svn for more info) that plugs git and svn together (svn becoming the remote repository for the git local repository).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that the branch you are working on is the one for `trunk` (I will call it `old-trunk`). Simply create a new branch from there

```
git checkout -b real-trunk remotes/trunk
```

Now make your changes to `real-trunk` and commit from there. Afterwards, simply rebase your old branch on the new one.

```
git svn dcommit
git checkout old-trunk
git rebase real-trunk
```

Now your earlier changes are based on the more recent changes you just did.