# How to get the latest SVN HEAD in git-svn?

Tags: git, repository, git-svn

I'm using `git-svn` and I'd like to update to the latest SVN HEAD.

When I type `git pull` it says:

```
fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352692/how-do-i-revert-a-git-svn-branch-to-svn-head) that I should do something like:

```
git checkout -b real-trunk remotes/trunk
```

But I don't understand the command. What's `remote-trunk`? In any case, `git` gives an error:

```
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'remotes/trunk' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

Here is my `.git/config`:

```
$ cat .git/config 
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = http://name.xyz.com/svn/trunk/project
        fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

Also, can anyone tell me how to revert all changes that I made in my git checkout? I want to be back at the fresh SVN HEAD version.

Answer (score 5):

For updating instead of "git pull":

```
git svn rebase
```

I guess you already have refs/heads/master corresponding your refs/remotes/git-svn, so work with it, you need no "real-trunk".

"git checkout" doesn't perform any changes, it just changes your current branch. You may change your current branch back but using "git checkout your_previous_commit_or_branch".

"git checkout -b branchname" creates a new branch. To delete a branch use " git branch -D branchname".

Comment: Thanks! Now one more problem: I have several local modifications that I'd like to revert first. Because if I do `git svn rebase` it says: 
`file.cpp: needs update`
`update-index --refresh: command returned error: 1`

Comment: You always should have a clean working tree before "git svn rebase", it is by design. Usually I commit my local changes and only then get new changes. Then after that I can amend my local commit (by "git commit --amend"). Some people use "git stash" for that.